# Cannot bind parameter to SQL statement using PHP PDO with MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

**Background**

Development environment:

PHP 7.0.4 with Apache 2.4.16 on Windows 10 x64

SQL Server 2014 Standard

SQL statement is executed through PHP PDO to the SQL server using ODBC `SQL Server` Driver

**Problem**

Cannot fetch any result when executing a query contains sub-query

Besides the following example, all other queries contains sub-query fails and some of the query need to handle direct input from the user therefore need sanitation to avoid SQL injection.

**Assumed Successful Code**

```
$dblink = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$db",  $user, $password);
$stmt = $dblink->prepare("SELECT * , ( SELECT RTRIM([Permission]) FROM [StaffLogin] WHERE [Staff].[StaffID] = [StaffLogin].[StaffID] ) AS [Permission] FROM [Staff] WHERE [StaffID] = ?");
$stmt->bindValue( 1 , "00522" , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But the above code returns no result.

**Work Around Code**

```
$dblink = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$db", $user, $password);
$stmt = $dblink->prepare("SELECT * , ( SELECT RTRIM([Permission]) FROM [StaffLogin] WHERE [Staff].[StaffID] = [StaffLogin].[StaffID] ) AS [Permission] FROM [Staff] WHERE [StaffID] = '00522'");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This code return one row of record.

**Edit**

Both of the following have tried

```
$stmt->bindValue( 1 , "00522" , PDO::PARAM_INT); // No result
$stmt->bindValue( 1 , "00522" , PDO::PARAM_STR); // No result
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding an integer when you actually want to bind a string:

```
$stmt->bindValue( 1 , "00522" , PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this one, I have tried both `PDO::PARAM_STR` and `PDO::PARAM_INT` but still no luck.